# Django urls and file structure for templates

Tags: python, django, templates, django-urls

I'm using Django 1.9.8 and started learning by following [the official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/). The official tutorial emphasised reusabilitiy and "plugability". From there I followed [this](http://blog.narenarya.in/right-way-django-authentication.html) tutorial on authorization. Although I was able to get the authorization tutorial to work, one thing about it that I didn't like (or just don't understand) is why the project's `urls.py` file contains several app specific urls, rather than placing them in the app's `urls.py` file and just including that file in the project's `urls.py` file. That seems to go against what the official tutorial emphasizes. I understand each project may have different URL's for login/logout/register, etc... depending on the API and will still have to be edited, but I feel like changing them in one place makes more sense and keeps things neater.

The name of the project is authtest and the name of the app is log

```
#log/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth import views
from log.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('log.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm }), #move this to authtest/urls.py
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}), #move this to authtest/urls.py
]
```

Now for the app's `urls.py` file

```
#authtest/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

This works 100%, so now for the first question. **Is there any reason I shouldn't move the log app specific urls (login & logout) out of the project's urls.py file (log/urls.py) and put them into the app's urls.py file (authtest/urls.py)?** Maybe there are reasons for authentication not to, but what about if I was making a different app?

Now for my second question, which I suppose depends on the answer to the first question. The authorization tutorial places the login.html, logout.html, and home.html templates in the project's root templates folder. The Django tutorial suggests putting them within an app's templates directory, and within that directory, another directory named whatever the app is called (for namespacing). **What do I have to change if I move the app specific template files from the project's templates folder, to the log app's templates folder?**

This is the current file structure from the authorization tutorial I followed

```
 authtest
|...authtest
|...|...settings.py
|...|...urls.py
|...log
|...|...settings.py
|...|...urls.py
|...|...views.py
|...manage.py
|...templates
|...|...base.html
|...|...home.html
|...|...login.html
|...static
```

This is how I assumed it should be based on how the official tutorial suggests to use templates.

```
authtest
|...authtest
|...|...settings.py
|...|...urls.py
|...log
|...|...urls.py
|...|...views.py
|...|...templates
|...|...|...log        #namespace of the log app
|...|...|...|...base.html
|...|...|...|...home.html
|...|...|...|...login.html
|...manage.py
|...templates
|...static
```

When I move the files I get the following error `TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/` when I visit `http://localhost:8080/login/`. I'm assuming it's solely the urls.py files, but I'm not sure exactly what I have to change.

**edited for settings.py templates directive**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        #'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], #I also tried this
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: please post your settings.py showing the TEMPLATE_DIRS directive

Comment: It's largely preference. There are some small differences, but nothing major. About the `TemplateDoesNotExist`: the template name should be relative to whichever `templates` directory the template lives in. If you move it to `templates/log/base.html`, you should pass `log/base.html` to the `login` function. The `log` directory prevents name conflicts between multiple apps using `base.html` template.

Comment: @nkhumphreys Thanks, I updated my post

Comment: @knbk the thing is, I never created a login method in the log views.py file, so I'm not sure how to pass the file location. The authorization tutorial shows all of the code that I used.

Comment: @user1852176 That's the `template_name` parameter in your `urls.py`. You're already passing it to the view, you just need to change it to this: `url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'log/login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm }),`

Comment: @knbk I tried that and got "TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/" error. In the traceback it shows that Django is trying to load it from within the project root templates directory, not from the app's templates directory. It's showing Django is trying to retrieve it from `/Users/.../DjangoProjects/authtest/templates/log/login.html` rather than `/Users/.../DjangoProjects/authtest/log/templates/log/login.html` . Please take a look above at the file structure (the second one shown) for a better representation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `settings.py` you need to add the `loaders` key in `OPTIONS` section. This specifies how django finds your `template files`. If you weren't specifying the `OPTIONS` key, the `APP_DIRS` settings should have been enough.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
    'DIRS': [
        str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
    ],
    'OPTIONS': {
        # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug
        'debug': DEBUG,
        # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types
        'loaders': [
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
        ],
        # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors

    },
},
```

]

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#loader-types for more info

Comment: I partially got it working. The log app was missing from the installed apps. I added it and kept my original templates directive. I changed some text on my login file (in the app's templates directory) and the changes appeared. I then renamed the project's templates folder just to test, but I got an error stating that my base.html file doesn't exist. Django is still looking for the base.html file in the project's templates folder, but I don't recall defining it anywhere in my settings or urls.py files. I think it's some of Django's "magic" at work, but I don't know where to look

Comment: you need to change your ` {% extend base.html %}` in the template folder of the log app to `{% extend log/base.html %}` since that is the new path

Comment: Does that mean it's a better idea to keep base.html in my project's templates directory and just move app-specific ones to that app? Will I have to extend that file for every app I add to the project?

Comment: yes it is. You could choose to create a `base.html` in the app directory which directly extends the project's `base.html`, then other html files in the app directory extends the local `base.html` file